# Importing data into core data from a csv file on a server

Tags: xcode, parsing, core-data, csv

I'm trying to read a data from a CSV file that is on a server. This file has a very large amount of data. Currently I'm reading this file using a NSURLREQUEST as shown below:

```
 -(void)serverConnect{
      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://spider90.dyndns.org:8080/sid/test.csv"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];

      NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  }

-(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

       response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSString *stripped1 = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

       NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stripped1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
       NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
       NSMutableArray *contentArray1 = [NSMutableArray array];
       NSArray *components;
       NSString *startpoint;

       for (int i=0;i<[rows count]; i++) {

           if(i == 0 || [[rows objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
               continue;
             }
           components = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

         if(i == 1){

           startpoint = [components objectAtIndex:0];

           NSLog(@"startpoint:%@",startpoint);

        }


       id x = [components objectAtIndex:0] ;
       id y = [components objectAtIndex:1];
       id z = [components objectAtIndex:2];

      [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",y,@"Y", nil]];
      [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",z,@"Y", nil]];
      NSLog(@"Contents of Uterus Contraction: %@",contentArray);
      NSLog(@"Contents of Heart Beat: %@",contentArray1);

}
      [_graphHostingView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000, 1000)];
       _graphHostingView.scrollEnabled = YES;
       _graphHostingView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
       _graphHostingView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
       _graphHostingView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

       self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:contentArray andString:startpoint];
       self.scatterPlot1 = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:contentArray1 andString:startpoint];
       [self.scatterPlot plot1];
       [self.scatterPlot1 plot2];

}
```

When I tried reading this file, I ended up at this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'.

I was suggested to try using a core data to store the data from the file. The problem lies with the file. It is being updated live and I need to get back to the previous value that I have added from the file into the database. Is there any suggestions that can direct me to what I'm looking for? The data range is around 21K plus lines of data. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDbId.jpg - sample screenshot of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment but I'm guessing one or many of the lines are blank so although components is a NSArray not a NSMutableArray, the blank lines in the file are causing the problem.